# Making a dictionary from file, first word is key in each line then other four numbers are to be a tuple value

Tags: python, file, dictionary, tuples

This dictionary is supposed to take the three letter country code of a country, i.e, GRE for great britain, and then take the four consecutive numbers after it as a tuple. it should be something like this:
{GRE:(204,203,112,116)} and continue doing that for every single country in the list. The txt file goes down like so:

```
Country,Games,Gold,Silver,Bronze
AFG,13,0,0,2
ALG,15,5,2,8
ARG,40,18,24,28
ARM,10,1,2,9
ANZ,2,3,4,5 etc.;
```

This isn't actually code i just wanted to show it is formatted.
I need my program to skip the first line because it's a header. Here's what my code looks like thus far:

```
def medals(goldMedals):
    infile = open(goldMedals, 'r')
    medalDict = {}
    for line in infile:
        if infile[line] != 0:
            key = line[0:3]
            value = line[3:].split(',')
            medalDict[key] = value
    print(medalDict)
    infile.close()
    return medalDict

medals('GoldMedals.txt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop should be like:

```
next(infile)  # Skip the first line
for line in infile:
    words = line.split(',')
    medalDict[words[0]] = tuple(map(int, words[1:]))
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. My only question is that do I need an if statement to ignore the first line? I can't find it anywhere in the returned dictionary but I'm not for sure

Comment: You need to use `next(infile)` to skip the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    answer = {}
    for line in infile:
        k,v = line.strip().split(',',1)
        answer[k] = tuple(int(i) for i in v.split(','))
```

Answer (score 0):

A variation on a theme, I'd convert all the remaining cols to ints, and I'd use a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

with open('file.txt') as fin:
    # The first line names the columns
    lines = iter(fin)
    columns = lines.next().strip().split(',')
    row = namedtuple('Row', columns[1:])
    results = {}
    for line in lines:
        columns = line.strip().split(',')
        results[columns[0]] = row(*(int(c) for c in columns[1:]))

# Results is now a dict to named tuples
```

This has the nice feature of 1) skipping the first line and 2) providing both offset and named access to the rows:

```
# These both work to return the 'Games' column
results['ALG'].Games
results['ALG'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think inspectorG4dget's answer is the most readable...  but for those playing code golf:

```
with open('medals.txt', 'r') as infile:
    headers = infile.readline()
    dict([(i[0], tuple(i[1:])) for i in [list(line.strip().split(',')) for line in infile]])
```